# jquery s3slider slider, how to change effects?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use this http://www.serie3.info/s3slider pluggin for my project how do i change the efect to simple fade in face out  , currently its coming with extra effect (somthing like glow fade in fade out)

demo : http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration

Comment: Looking at the plugin source, it is just using fadeIn and fadeOut.  Can you explain what you mean by 'glow' or what you would expect the transition to look like?

Comment: I want to use a simple fade in fade out script with caption

Comment: That is what this plugin and the demo does, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try any of these jquery plugins as well.

- http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/
- http://wowslider.com/html-slideshow-silence-blur-demo.html